# Excel Macro for updating "change date" makes Excel crash

Tags: vba, excel

I have an [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) file in which I have several tables with the field "Last change:". If any change is made to that table, the field should update to the current date.

I implemented a macro that did what it should, but unfortunately it disabled the "Reverse" (Strg + Z) function which was very annoying. Therefore I edited the macro such that the Reverse-functionality would work again. My macro now looks like this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Merker

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
        Application.OnUndo "Rev. Change", "Wiederherstellen"
        Merker = Cells(3, 2)
        Cells(3, 2) = Date
    End If
End Sub

Sub Wiederherstellen()
    Cells(3, 2) = Merker
End Sub
```

When I apply this macro, Excel crashes as soon as I make a change to the document.
Is there something invalid in my code? I am really wondering since there is no error message or wrong behavior but only the application crashing. This crash happens reliably every time.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @Remou I understand why you re-tagged this, and that is technically correct, but very few questions would remained tagged [tag:VBA] if this was widely adopted. Which perhaps means this tag should be culled. Be that as it may given the Office Apps can automate the rest of the Office family IMHO the [tag:VBA] should be left on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You event is likely to be calling itself in an infinite loop. Try disabling Events to stop the code re-calling itself on this line `Cells(3, 2) = Date`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.OnUndo "Rev. Change", "Wiederherstellen"
        Merker = Cells(3, 2)
        Cells(3, 2) = Date
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```